# Cassandra - SimpleStrategy requires a replication_factor strategy option

Tags: java, cassandra

I have a small java code that should create a keyspace and columnFamily and add some values to it.
But whatever I do, i keep getting one or the other error.

Now I am getting this error - SimpleStrategy requires a replication_factor strategy option
whereas I have declared replication_factor as 1 as follows -

keyspaceDef = HFactory.createKeyspaceDefinition(                    "MyKeyspace", ThriftKsDef.DEF_STRATEGY_CLASS, 1, Arrays                     .asList(cfDef));

I am able to create KeySpace from cqlsh, only from Java I am having this issue.
Also, when I check from cqlsh, and list the Keyspaces in system, I do find the keyspace created there.

So whats is wrong, I have no idea.

Here is my whole code:

```
   package com.examples.cassandra;

   import java.util.Arrays;
   import org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Column;
   import org.apache.cassandra.thrift.ColumnPath;
   import me.prettyprint.cassandra.serializers.StringSerializer;
   import me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.ThriftKsDef;
   import me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.template.ColumnFamilyResult;
   import me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.template.ColumnFamilyTemplate;
   import me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.template.ColumnFamilyUpdater;
   import me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.template.ThriftColumnFamilyTemplate;
   import me.prettyprint.hector.api.Cluster;
   import me.prettyprint.hector.api.Keyspace;
   import me.prettyprint.hector.api.ddl.ColumnFamilyDefinition;
   import me.prettyprint.hector.api.ddl.ComparatorType;
   import me.prettyprint.hector.api.ddl.KeyspaceDefinition;
   import me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HectorException;
   import me.prettyprint.hector.api.factory.HFactory;

   public class test {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO 
    Cluster cluster = HFactory.getOrCreateCluster("test-cluster",
            "localhost:9160");

    KeyspaceDefinition keyspaceDef = cluster.describeKeyspace("MyKeyspace");

    // If keyspace does not exist, the CFs don't exist either. => create them.
    if (keyspaceDef == null) {
        ColumnFamilyDefinition cfDef = HFactory.createColumnFamilyDefinition(
                "MyKeyspace", "ColumnFamilyName", ComparatorType.BYTESTYPE);
        keyspaceDef = HFactory.createKeyspaceDefinition(
                "MyKeyspace", ThriftKsDef.DEF_STRATEGY_CLASS, 1, Arrays
                        .asList(cfDef));    

        cluster.addKeyspace(keyspaceDef);
    }
    Keyspace ksp = HFactory.createKeyspace("MyKeyspace", cluster);
    ColumnFamilyTemplate<String, String> template = 
        new ThriftColumnFamilyTemplate<String, String>(ksp,
                                                       "ColumnFamilyName", 
                                                       StringSerializer.get(),        
                                                       StringSerializer.get());
    ColumnFamilyUpdater<String, String> updater = template.createUpdater("a key");
    updater.setString("domain", "www.datastax.com");
    updater.setString("time", "sdjsakldl");
    updater.setString("ID", "dadsadas");

    try {
        template.update(updater);
    } catch (HectorException e) {
        // do something ...
    }
    updater = template.createUpdater("2 key");
    updater.setString("domain", "www.ax.com");
    updater.setString("time", "sdj");
    try {
        template.update(updater);
    } catch (HectorException e) {
        // do something ...
        System.out.println();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        ColumnFamilyResult<String, String> res = template.queryColumns("2 key");
        String value = res.getString("domain");
        System.out.println(value);
        // value should be "www.datastax.com" as per our previous insertion.
    } catch (HectorException e) {
        // do something ...
        System.out.println();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static Object string(String string) {

    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error said that you need to set a replication_factor when creating a keyspace with a SimpleStrategy.

However, when you do this :

```
HFactory.createKeyspaceDefinition("MyKeyspace", ThriftKsDef.DEF_STRATEGY_CLASS, 1, Arrays.asList(cfDef));
cluster.addKeyspace(keyspaceDef);
```

You correctly create the **definition** of a keyspace.
But then, when you do this :

```
Keyspace ksp = HFactory.createKeyspace("MyKeyspace", cluster);
```

it doesn't look like it'll re-use the previously created definition, I would say it'll create a keyspace with default settings.

Javadoc of the HFactory class : http://hector-client.github.io/hector/source/content/API/core/1.0-1/me/prettyprint/hector/api/factory/HFactory.html